# VBA: change cell color in defined range

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare data between two sheets (VPN and VPN_DEF). If on sheet VPN cells between range C25 and C40 change value, they need to be colored yellow.
I've found the code below and it is working, but it checks the whole document. How can i specify the range C25:C40?

```
Sub CompareSheets()
Dim rngCell As Range

For Each rngCell In Worksheets("VPN").UsedRange

    If Not rngCell = Worksheets("VPN_DEF").Cells(rngCell.Row, rngCell.Column) Then
         rngCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If

Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Try replacing `Worksheets("VPN").UsedRange` with `Worksheets("VPN").Range("C25:C40")`...

Comment: It works, but if you will (sometime) need to process a huge range it is good to not color the cells one by one. It is good to set a `Union` Range and color all its cells at once, after the loop...